# How to fix CrudRepository save() when its doesn't commit to database?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Need help when trying to save through this method, my hibernate debug doesn't show any error, no one error catch in this method

it is not committed, already try everything includes saveAndFlush() from JPARepositiry, all possible annotation, check whole my algorithm and logic. I thought it's related to my PostgreSQL configuration or my bidirectional relationship between related entities. But still, nothing showed up on my table in the database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-pegawai-status", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> savePlanningPegawaiStatus(@Valid @RequestBody PlanningPegawaiStatusVO vo,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> result = servicePermohonanStatus.savePlanningPegawaiStatus(vo);
            if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(result.get("noRec"))) {
                mapHeaderMessage.put(WebConstants.HttpHeaderInfo.LABEL_SUCCESS, getMessage(MessageResource.LABEL_SUCCESS, request));
                return RestUtil.getJsonResponse(result, HttpStatus.CREATED, mapHeaderMessage);
            } else {
                return RestUtil.getJsonResponse(result, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } catch (ServiceVOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Got exception {} when savePlanningPegawaiStatus", e.getMessage());
            addHeaderMessage(Constants.MessageInfo.ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
            return RestUtil.getJsonHttptatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, mapHeaderMessage);
        } catch (JpaSystemException jse) {
            LOGGER.error("Got exception {} when savePlanningPegawaiStatus", jse.getMessage());
            addHeaderMessage(Constants.MessageInfo.ERROR_MESSAGE, jse.getMessage());
            return RestUtil.getJsonHttptatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, mapHeaderMessage);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            LOGGER.error("Got exception {} when savePlanningPegawaiStatus", exp.getMessage());
            addHeaderMessage(Constants.MessageInfo.ERROR_MESSAGE, exp.getMessage());
            return RestUtil.getJsonHttptatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, mapHeaderMessage);
        }
    }
```

```
package com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.entities;

    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.base.BaseTransaction;
    import com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.helper.Caption;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="ListTanggalCuti_T")
    public class ListTanggalCuti extends BaseTransaction{

    @Caption(value="tgl")
    @Column(name="tgl", nullable=true)
    private Date tgl;

    @Caption(value="Approval Status")
    @Column(name="ApprovalStatus", nullable=true)
    private Boolean approvalStatus;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Planning Pegawai Status")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectPlanningPegawaiStatusFK")
    private PlanningPegawaiStatus planningPegawaiStatus;

    @Column(name="ObjectPlanningPegawaiStatusFK", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String planningPegawaiStatusId;

    public Date getTgl() {
        return tgl;
    }

    public void setTgl(Date tgl) {
        this.tgl = tgl;
    }

    public Boolean getApprovalStatus() {
        return approvalStatus;
    }

    public void setApprovalStatus(Boolean approvalStatus) {
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;
    }

    public PlanningPegawaiStatus getPlanningPegawaiStatus() {
        return planningPegawaiStatus;
    }

    public void setPlanningPegawaiStatus(PlanningPegawaiStatus planningPegawaiStatus) {
        this.planningPegawaiStatus = planningPegawaiStatus;
    }

    public String getPlanningPegawaiStatusId() {
        return planningPegawaiStatusId;
    }

    public void setPlanningPegawaiStatusId(String planningPegawaiStatusId) {
        this.planningPegawaiStatusId = planningPegawaiStatusId;
    }
    }
```

```
package com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.entities;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.base.BaseTransaction;
    import com.jasamedika.medifirst2000.helper.Caption;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PlanningPegawaiStatus_T")
    public class PlanningPegawaiStatus extends BaseTransaction{

    @Caption(value="No Planning")
    @Column(name="NoPlanning", length=15, nullable=true)
    private String noPlanning;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Pegawai")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectPegawaiFk")
    private Pegawai pegawai;

    //  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    //  @Caption(value="Object Jabatan Cuti")
    //  @JoinColumn(name="ObjectJabatanCutiFk")
    //  private Jabatan jabatanCuti;

    @Column(name="ObjectPegawaiFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer pegawaiId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Status Pegawai Plan")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectStatusPegawaiPlanFk")
    private StatusPegawai statusPegawaiPlan;

    @Column(name="ObjectStatusPegawaiPlanFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer statusPegawaiPlanId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "planningPegawaiStatus", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ListTanggalCuti> listTanggal = new HashSet<ListTanggalCuti>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Departemen")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectDepartemenFk")
    private Departemen departemen;

    @Column(name="ObjectDepartemenFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer departemenId;

    @Caption(value="Deskripsi Status Pegawai Plan")
    @Column(name="DeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String deskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan;

    @Caption(value="Keterangan Lainya Plan")
    @Column(name="KeteranganLainyaPlan", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String keteranganLainyaPlan;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object No SK")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectNoSkFk")
    private SuratKeputusan noSk;

    @Column(name="ObjectNoSkFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer noSkId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Status Pegawai Exec")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectStatusPegawaiExecFk")
    private StatusPegawai statusPegawaiExec;

    @Column(name="ObjectStatusPegawaiExecFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer statusPegawaiExecId;    

    @Caption(value="Deskripsi Status Pegawai Exec")
    @Column(name="DeskripsiStatusPegawaiExec", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String deskripsiStatusPegawaiExec;

    @Caption(value="Keterangan Lainya Exec")
    @Column(name="KeteranganLainyaExec", length=1000, nullable=true)
    private String keteranganLainyaExec;

    @Caption(value="Tgl Pengajuan")
    @Column(name="TglPengajuan", nullable=true)
    private Date tglPengajuan;

    @Caption(value="Tgl Keputusan")
    @Column(name="TglKeputusan", nullable=true)
    private Date tglKeputusan;

    @Caption(value="Approval Status")
    @Column(name="ApprovalStatus", nullable=true)
    private Integer approvalStatus;

    @Caption(value="jumlahHari")
    @Column(name="jumlahHari", nullable=true)
    private Integer jumlahHari;

    //  @Caption(value="keterangan")
    //  @Column(name="keterangan", nullable=true)
    //  private String keterangan;

    @Caption(value="Jenis Perawatan")
    @Column(name="jenisPerawatan", nullable=true)
    private Integer jenisPerawatan;

    @Caption(value="Alamat Selama Cuti")
    @Column(name="alamatCuti", nullable=true)
    private String alamatCuti;

    @Caption(value="Nomor Telepon")
    @Column(name="nomorTelepon", nullable=true)
    private String nomorTelepon;

    @Caption(value="Nomor Surat Tugas")
    @Column(name="noSuratTugas", nullable=true)
    private String noSuratTugas;

    @Caption(value="Nomor Nota Dinas")
    @Column(name="noNotaDinas", nullable=true)
    private String noNotaDinas;

    @Caption(value="Tgl Nota Dinas")
    @Column(name="TglNotaDinas", nullable=true)
    private Date tglNotaDinas;

    @Caption(value="Alamat Tugas Dinas")
    @Column(name="alamatTugas", nullable=true)
    private String alamatTugas; 

    @ManyToOne(optional=true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Caption(value="Object Jabatan Pemberi Nota Dinas")
    @JoinColumn(name="ObjectJabatanPemberiNotaDinasFk", nullable=true)
    private Jabatan jabatanPemberiNotaDinas;

    @Column(name="ObjectJabatanPemberiNotaDinasFk", nullable=true, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer jabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas;

    @Caption(value="is Cuti Luar Negeri")
    @Column(name="isCutiLuarNegeri", nullable=true)
    private Boolean isCutiLuarNegeri;

    public String getNoPlanning() {
        return noPlanning;
    }

    public void setNoPlanning(String noPlanning) {
        this.noPlanning = noPlanning;
    }

    public Pegawai getPegawai() {
        return pegawai;
    }

    public void setPegawai(Pegawai pegawai) {
        this.pegawai = pegawai;
    }

    public Integer getPegawaiId() {
        return pegawaiId;
    }

    public void setPegawaiId(Integer pegawaiId) {
        this.pegawaiId = pegawaiId;
    }

    //  public Jabatan getJabatanCuti() {
    //      return jabatanCuti;
    //  }

    //  public void setJabatanCuti(Jabatan jabatanCuti) {
    //      this.jabatanCuti = jabatanCuti;
    //  }

    public StatusPegawai getStatusPegawaiPlan() {
        return statusPegawaiPlan;
    }

    public void setStatusPegawaiPlan(StatusPegawai statusPegawaiPlan) {
        this.statusPegawaiPlan = statusPegawaiPlan;
    }

    public Integer getStatusPegawaiPlanId() {
        return statusPegawaiPlanId;
    }

    public void setStatusPegawaiPlanId(Integer statusPegawaiPlanId) {
        this.statusPegawaiPlanId = statusPegawaiPlanId;
    }

    public Departemen getDepartemen() {
        return departemen;
    }

    public void setDepartemen(Departemen departemen) {
        this.departemen = departemen;
    }

    public Integer getDepartemenId() {
        return departemenId;
    }

    public void setDepartemenId(Integer departemenId) {
        this.departemenId = departemenId;
    }

    public String getDeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan() {
        return deskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan;
    }

    public void setDeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan(String deskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan) {
        this.deskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan = deskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan;
    }

    public String getKeteranganLainyaPlan() {
        return keteranganLainyaPlan;
    }

    public void setKeteranganLainyaPlan(String keteranganLainyaPlan) {
        this.keteranganLainyaPlan = keteranganLainyaPlan;
    }

    public SuratKeputusan getNoSk() {
        return noSk;
    }

    public void setNoSk(SuratKeputusan noSk) {
        this.noSk = noSk;
    }

    public Integer getNoSkId() {
        return noSkId;
    }

    public void setNoSkId(Integer noSkId) {
        this.noSkId = noSkId;
    }

    public StatusPegawai getStatusPegawaiExec() {
        return statusPegawaiExec;
    }

    public void setStatusPegawaiExec(StatusPegawai statusPegawaiExec) {
        this.statusPegawaiExec = statusPegawaiExec;
    }

    public Integer getStatusPegawaiExecId() {
        return statusPegawaiExecId;
    }

    public void setStatusPegawaiExecId(Integer statusPegawaiExecId) {
        this.statusPegawaiExecId = statusPegawaiExecId;
    }
    public String getDeskripsiStatusPegawaiExec() {
        return deskripsiStatusPegawaiExec;
    }

    public void setDeskripsiStatusPegawaiExec(String deskripsiStatusPegawaiExec) {
        this.deskripsiStatusPegawaiExec = deskripsiStatusPegawaiExec;
    }

    public String getKeteranganLainyaExec() {
        return keteranganLainyaExec;
    }

    public void setKeteranganLainyaExec(String keteranganLainyaExec) {
        this.keteranganLainyaExec = keteranganLainyaExec;
    }

    public Date getTglPengajuan() {
        return tglPengajuan;
    }

    public void setTglPengajuan(Date tglPengajuan) {
        this.tglPengajuan = tglPengajuan;
    }

    public Date getTglKeputusan() {
        return tglKeputusan;
    }

    public void setTglKeputusan(Date tglKeputusan) {
        this.tglKeputusan = tglKeputusan;
    }

    public Integer getApprovalStatus() {
        return approvalStatus;
    }

    public void setApprovalStatus(Integer approvalStatus) {
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;
    }

    public Integer getJumlahHari() {
        return jumlahHari;
    }

    public void setJumlahHari(Integer jumlahHari) {
        this.jumlahHari = jumlahHari;
    }

    public Set<ListTanggalCuti> getListTanggal() {
        return listTanggal;
    }

    public void setListTanggal(Set<ListTanggalCuti> listTanggal) {
        this.listTanggal = listTanggal;
    }

    //  public String getKeterangan() {
    //      return keterangan;
    //  }

    //  public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
    //      this.keterangan = keterangan;
    //  }

    public Integer getJenisPerawatan() {
        return jenisPerawatan;
    }

    public void setJenisPerawatan(Integer jenisPerawatan) {
        this.jenisPerawatan = jenisPerawatan;
    }

    public String getAlamatCuti() {
        return alamatCuti;
    }

    public void setAlamatCuti(String alamatCuti) {
        this.alamatCuti = alamatCuti;
    }

    public String getNomorTelepon() {
        return nomorTelepon;
    }

    public void setNomorTelepon(String nomorTelepon) {
        this.nomorTelepon = nomorTelepon;
    }

    public String getNoSuratTugas() {
        return noSuratTugas;
    }

    public void setNoSuratTugas(String noSuratTugas) {
        this.noSuratTugas = noSuratTugas;
    }

    public String getNoNotaDinas() {
        return noNotaDinas;
    }

    public void setNoNotaDinas(String noNotaDinas) {
        this.noNotaDinas = noNotaDinas;
    }

    public Date getTglNotaDinas() {
        return tglNotaDinas;
    }

    public void setTglNotaDinas(Date tglNotaDinas) {
        this.tglNotaDinas = tglNotaDinas;
    }

    public String getAlamatTugas() {
        return alamatTugas;
    }

    public void setAlamatTugas(String alamatTugas) {
        this.alamatTugas = alamatTugas;
    }

    public Jabatan getJabatanPemberiNotaDinas() {
        return jabatanPemberiNotaDinas;
    }

    public void setJabatanPemberiNotaDinas(Jabatan jabatanPemberiNotaDinas) {
        this.jabatanPemberiNotaDinas = jabatanPemberiNotaDinas;
    }

    public Integer getJabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas() {
        return jabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas;
    }

    public void setJabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas(Integer jabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas) {
        this.jabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas = jabatanIdPemberiNotaDinas;
    }

    public Boolean getIsCutiLuarNegeri() {
        return isCutiLuarNegeri;
    }

    public void setIsCutiLuarNegeri(Boolean isCutiLuarNegeri) {
        this.isCutiLuarNegeri = isCutiLuarNegeri;
    }

    }
```

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Map<String, Object> savePlanningPegawaiStatus(PlanningPegawaiStatusVO vo) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

        boolean statusTanggalPermohonan = validateTanggalPermohonan(vo.getListTanggal(), vo.getPegawai().getId());
        if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(statusTanggalPermohonan) && !statusTanggalPermohonan) {
            result.put("bisaCuti", statusTanggalPermohonan);
            result.put("status", "Tanggal Permohonan sudah pernah diajukan!"); //Validasi tanggal permohonan yang sudah diajukan
            return result;
        } else {
            Integer day = 0;
            if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo)) {
                PlanningPegawaiStatus planningPegawaiStatus = planningPegawaiStatusConverter.transferVOToModel(vo,
                        new PlanningPegawaiStatus());
                String noPlanning = noUsulan().get("noUsulan").toString();
                if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(noPlanning)) {
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setNoPlanning(noPlanning);
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setStatusEnabled(true);
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getStatusPegawaiPlan())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setStatusPegawaiPlan(
                                statusPegawaiConverter.transferVOToModel(vo.getStatusPegawaiPlan(), new StatusPegawai()));
                    }
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getJabatanPemberiNotaDinas())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setJabatanPemberiNotaDinas(
                                jabatanConverter.transferVOToModel(vo.getJabatanPemberiNotaDinas(), new Jabatan()));
                    }
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setApprovalStatus(0);
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getPegawai())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus
                                .setPegawai(pegawaiConverter.transferVOToModel(vo.getPegawai(), new Pegawai()));
                    }
                    Set<ListTanggalCuti> listTanggal = new HashSet<ListTanggalCuti>();

                    for (ListTanggalCutiVO date : vo.getListTanggal()) {
                        day++;
                        ListTanggalCuti tanggal = listTanggalConverter.transferVOToModel(date, new ListTanggalCuti());
                        tanggal.setPlanningPegawaiStatus(planningPegawaiStatus);
                        tanggal.setStatusEnabled(true);
                        listTanggal.add(tanggal);
                    }
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setJumlahHari(day);
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setListTanggal(listTanggal);
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getDeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setDeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan(vo.getDeskripsiStatusPegawaiPlan());
                    }
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getKeteranganLainyaPlan())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setKeteranganLainyaPlan(vo.getKeteranganLainyaPlan());
                    }

                    //Set Alamat Cuti dan No Telepon
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setAlamatCuti(vo.getAlamatCuti());
                    planningPegawaiStatus.setNomorTelepon(vo.getNomorTelepon());

                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getAlamatTugas())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setAlamatTugas(vo.getAlamatTugas());
                    }
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getNoSuratTugas())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setNoSuratTugas(vo.getNoSuratTugas());
                    }
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getNoNotaDinas())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setNoNotaDinas(vo.getNoNotaDinas());
                    }
                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(vo.getTglNotaDinas())) {
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setTglNotaDinas(vo.getTglNotaDinas());
                    }

                    planningPegawaiStatus.setIsCutiLuarNegeri(vo.getIsCutiLuarNegeri());

                    if (CommonUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(planningPegawaiStatus)) {
                        List<String> listTgl = new ArrayList<>();
                        planningPegawaiStatus.setStatusEnabled(true);
                        PlanningPegawaiStatus planningPegawaiStatusResult = planningPegawaiStatusDao
                                .save(planningPegawaiStatus);
                        for (ListTanggalCuti listTanggalCuti : planningPegawaiStatusResult.getListTanggal()) {
                            listTgl.add(listTanggalCuti.getNoRec());
                        }
                        result.put("listTgl", listTgl);
                        result.put("noRec", planningPegawaiStatusResult.getNoRec());
                        result.put("bisaCuti", statusTanggalPermohonan);
                    }
                }

            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

PlanningPegawaiStatusVO and ListTanggalCutiVO just related value object class, transferVOToModel() is a method for data access from value object class to model

I'm finally realized that sometimes its commit and sometimes it isn't. And then when it isn't inserted to the database, also return with HttpStatus.CREATED an ERROR_MESSAGE like could not extract ResultSet from GenericJDBCException but it does not come from catch

Comment: What return code do you receive : HttpStatus.CREATED or HttpStatus.OK ?
Can you show us the source code of the `servicePermohonanStatus.savePlanningPegawaiStatus(...)` method ?

Comment: that method return HttpStatus.CREATED

Comment: I just edited my question with the service method, thank you, Marc

Comment: what is `planningPegawaiStatusDao` ?

Comment: Ensure by adding few logs that your program really goes where you believe it should. Because they are so many conditions that even if your function returns CREATED, it could have done nothing.

Comment: `planningPegawaiStatusDao` is the @Repository thing

Comment: when tried to debug hibernate, there is no error but generated insert query and doesn't exist in the database